# RemoteControlClient in service, not showing widget

Tags: android, lockscreen, remote-control

I have an media player service with custom decoders for playing streams. I tried all I could find on the web for registering media control buttons on the screen, but they don't show up.

The service works as it follows:

1. In `onCreate()` I did the following:

   ```
   audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
   Intent buttonIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON);
   ComponentName component = new ComponentName(this, MediaControlReceiver.class);

   buttonIntent.setComponent(component);
   PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 0, buttonIntent, 0);
   myRemoteControlClient = new RemoteControlClient(pendingIntent);

   audioManager.registerRemoteControlClient(myRemoteControlClient);

   int flags = RemoteControlClient.FLAG_KEY_MEDIA_PREVIOUS
           | RemoteControlClient.FLAG_KEY_MEDIA_NEXT
           | RemoteControlClient.FLAG_KEY_MEDIA_PLAY
           | RemoteControlClient.FLAG_KEY_MEDIA_PAUSE
           | RemoteControlClient.FLAG_KEY_MEDIA_PLAY_PAUSE
           | RemoteControlClient.FLAG_KEY_MEDIA_STOP;
   myRemoteControlClient.setTransportControlFlags(flags);
   ```
2. When the service received a play message, I start the song and I call the following code for lockscreen buttons:

   ```
   int result = audioManager.requestAudioFocus(focusChangeListener,
           AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
           AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN);

   if (result == AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_REQUEST_GRANTED) {
       Log.d("RemoteControl", "Status: PLAY"  + result);
       myRemoteControlClient.setPlaybackState(RemoteControlClient.PLAYSTATE_PLAYING);
       setRemoteControlMetadata(null, "test", "test", 1);
   }
   ```

I also have a focus change listener registered, but with no use. Can you help me connect my application to widget buttons?